# Office 365 Login through intranet

Tags: c#, iis, office365

One of my client currently has an intranet site, where users can automatically log into Exchange 2010. This is all done through a custom form which authenticates against owaauth.dll. We provide a pre-defined username and password automatically in the form and the user logs into the mailbox, without any additional form of user authentication. They'd like to continue working like this, but this time, for Office 365.

What's important to know:

- No login wanted
- Usernames/passwords are known by the admins/developers
- Local AD and Azure AD are not connected and will not be connected
- Users authenticate against IIS, so there IS an authentication
- The mailbox is from a different domain than the local domain

What we've found so far is:
- You can use Office 365 to authenticate your own app (reversed from what we want)
- owaauth.dll does not exist anymore

We're very well aware that this isn't the perfect solution, but sometimes you just can't implement the best solution and still have the need for some functionality.

Authentication against Office 365 is not that hard, but we need the browser to do it, so the cookies and sessions and all that from Office 365 will be set properly.

Is there anybody that can shed a +light on this issue?

Comment: *Usernames/passwords are known by the admins/developers* **Call the security officer! Quick! Abandon ship!**

Answer (score 1):

The minute you have an O365 tenant, you have "Azure" AD by default. That is how all users are registered in O365, so you cant avoid it. Therefore I would suggest looking into [Azure Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) approach using service principal account that has rights for logon on behalf of users. Then somehow internally map them to users in IIS VS the other domain usernames. I assume that is how it works now.

Comment: The API is for server use, not to log you in from a client with username and password.

Comment: What Patrick is saying, is what we found out as well.

And of course, there is Azure AD. I never said anywhere that there isn't. The local AD and Azure AD are just not sync'd.

Comment: I dont necessarily get the question. From what I read you have a SSO scenario where users log on to IIS, I assume with the "different" Ad domain usernames, and then service account is used to get him further. However if he changes the username, he can get in there with other users email too?

Comment: Right now, the intranet site has local AD authentication. So the user cannot log in as someone else.

What we literally do: 
- Who are you?
- Check AD for his department
- Get the department mailbox credentials from our SQL server
- Log him into his department mailbox

So as Mr X he can only log into the mailbox of department X, because he cannot use a different username.

The same principle we'd like to use again, but then for logging into Office 365.

Comment: It sounds to me you are using shared mailboxes with known and stored usernames and passwords. So basically you need a GRAPH SSO scenario towards certain user from one application to another. In that case, use this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of